# execute shell script in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, shell, concatenation

I want to execute the following shell script

```
system('echo "
    rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.99.1 port 80 -> 192.168.99.1 port 8080
    rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.99.1 port 443 -> 192.168.99.1 port 4443
    " | sudo pfctl -ef - > /dev/null 2>&1; echo "==> Fowarding Ports: 80 -> 8080, 443 -> 4443 & Enabling pf"'
)
```

This works fine, i now want to pass the IP address loaded from a YAML file, i tried the following

**config.yaml**

```
configs:
    use: 'home'
    office:
        public_ip: '192.168.99.2'
    home:
        public_ip: '192.168.99.1'
```

Vagrantfile

```
require 'yaml'

current_dir    = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
configs        = YAML.load_file("#{current_dir}/config.yaml")
vagrant_config = configs['configs'][configs['configs']['use']]

system('echo "
    rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 80 -> '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 8080
    rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 443 -> '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 4443
    " | sudo pfctl -ef - > /dev/null 2>&1; echo "==> Fowarding Ports: 80 -> 8080, 443 -> 4443 & Enabling pf"'
)
```

The second method does not work, nor it shows any error, can someone point me to the right direction, what i want is to read public_ip dynamically from config file or variable

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I get the following output

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pfctl: pf already enabled
```

What can be possibly wrong?

Comment: What is the result from `vagrant_config['public_ip']`?

Comment: Run pfctl with the '-v' option to get more verbose output.  You may also want to try writing the rdr commands to a file and referencing that file as the '-f' option is to read from a file (piping may not work).

Comment: @SilverPhoenix I get 192.168.99.1, strangely it started working when i restarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For troubleshooting purposes, it would be wise to output the command you're going to run prior to sending it out to system.

```
cmd = 'echo "
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 80 -> '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 8080
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 443 -> '+vagrant_config['public_ip']+' port 4443
" | sudo pfctl -ef - > /dev/null 2>&1; echo "==> Fowarding Ports: 80 -> 8080, 443 -> 4443 & Enabling pf"'

puts "Command to run:\n\n#{cmd}"
system( cmd )
```

Then, it would be wise to make the output from the system command visible.  To make sure you get this feedback, I suggest you replace

`sudo pfctl -ef - > /dev/null 2>&1`

with (adding '-v' for more verbose output - [pfctl man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pfctl&sektion=8))

`sudo pfctl -efv -`

and then look for the output and/or error messages.

Then, once the bugs are sorted out, you can put it back into stealthy, quiet mode :D

Also, since you are running with `sudo` you'll need to make sure the shell you're running within has sudo privileges and also make sure you're not being prompted for a password unknowingly.

Comment: It does show me password prompt, when i enter it, it works, do you see anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Updated my question with the output

Comment: Strangely it started working when i restarted, thanks anyway for the help